# Can I go back to last used tab after closing one on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

After **closing** a tab on google chrome, it doesn't come back to the last active tab but to the one at its right, or left when the new tab is the rightmost.

For example :

- On tab 6/10
- Open and go to new tab, 11/11
- Close the tab, go back to 10/10 tab

Why is that? Is there a way to make it go to the last used tab? (6/10 in my example) I have to use Chrome for several reasons and being used to Firefox this is especially annoying. Honestly I can't believe that in 2018, the most popular browser doesn't do something as simple as that by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer is now obsolete. Here are some alternatives sugeested in the comments. I have not tried them yet.

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-customizer-2/jglbflnkbgbklegdblkohbbbheeeklej
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-options/fjccjnfkdkdmjohojoggodkigkjkkjhl

---

In order to configure where you want chrome to go after you closed a tab, you can use **[TabsPlus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabsplus/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii)**, an extension available on the Web Store.
[image]

You can choose to go back to the **last used tab** using this extension. I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: As of 2020, unfortunately it doesn't really work on Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build). I was enchanted by the idea, only to test and find it not working. Apparently it's a bug that happens if you have multiple chrome windows opened. There are more people commenting on the app's review about this. Since the last time this app was updated was in 2013, I doubt it'll ever work again.

Comment: Since the question is closed but was the first one that appeared on my Google search, and this answer doesn't apply, I'll leave a couple alternatives I've found and personally tested that actually work:
[[Tab Position Customizer 2]]  
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-customizer-2/jglbflnkbgbklegdblkohbbbheeeklej   
-------   
[[Tab Position Options]]   
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-options/fjccjnfkdkdmjohojoggodkigkjkkjhl